# Connection Database name on Visual Studio Code MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

So two questions:

1. What should I put for Connection Name in the Connection Assistant or is this just like any name that I can put.
2. What should should I put for Database Name in the Connection Assistant.

[image: Image of Connection Assistant]

Comment: I can't create one, as whenever I open an SQL file, it shows that I have to run on an active connection, but I don't have one/I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1.The connection name can be any name , so that you can identify it

ad 2. there you have to enter a database base name you want to connect to it is the same as `ÙSE Databásename`

if you have none defined you can use `mysql`

and then  create your database andapply the `ÙSE new_databsename`